# When making my html emails do I have to inline my CSS?

Tags: sendgrid-templates

Please help. thanks.

idk icl because I see other people internally creating their css and i thought that wasnt optimal

Answer (score 1):

It is better to inline CSS because of compatibility. You can check out: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/style-element/style-in-head/.

[image]

Here, we can see that the style tag is incompatible only with a few mobile clients. Based on your customer base, you can decide if you want to style tag in the head of emails